# Coldfusion Process Name

Tags: coldfusion, windows-services, process

What is the ColdFusion Process Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I have found the process name for ColdFusion:

`jrun.exe` - The process JRun JAR Launcher belongs to the software Macromedia JRun Application Server or JRun.exe or ColdFusion Graphing Server or Macromedia ColdFusion MX or jrun.exe by Macromedia Inc (www.macromedia.com).

Comment: If this is the answer you found, then you should accept it. Even though it is your answer.

Comment: And more specifically, jrun.exe is the process name in the task manager.  It may be a different "service" name in the services view in the control panel where you would start and stop it.

Comment: I shall do, hehe. Said I need to wait 2 days though, so will do it as I can.

Comment: Its worth noting that this is only the process name for a standard installation on Windows.  For installs not using JRUN then you're going to have something completely different. For example, people using JBoss or Tomcat.  Not to mention folks using other CFML engines such as Railo or OpenBD.

Answer (score 3):

In ColdFusion 10 there is a separate process named - coldfusion.exe found in cfusin/bin

There is also a running coldfusinsvc.exe (which is the ColdFusion Service Application) which might interest you as well.

CF10 onwards the application server is CF+Tomcat bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look with [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)?  Though some services share a process, non-builtin services probably don't.

If you can't tell which "svchost.exe" instance is running a particular service, hover over it, and it'll display the services it is hosting.

Answer (score 1):

JRUN is the underlying application server used by Adobe ColdFusion 8 and 9. Other version or flavours of CF runtimes and engines are dependent on the underlying server technology such as Tomcat, JBoss, Webspehere etc. Some common process names are java.exe, tomcat.exe, jrun.exe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Check that "Show processes from all users" in the Processes tab is checked.